# Dividing two pandas values

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset from the following commands

```
df.ab.value_counts()

Out[154]:

0    31196
1    18804
dtype: int64
```

I want to find the fraction of 1 out of total counts. So basically 18804/50000

I do the following:

```
(df.ab.value_counts()[1])/(df.ab.count())

Out[146]:

0
```

As you see it gives me zero while it should be 0.3768 (18804/50000)

Any idea why?

Edit II:

Any idea how to plot the bar graph of these two values 0 and 1 and their counts?

Comment: Are you on python 2..If yes then u will get 0 when tried with '/' (integer division in python 2). try doing from __future__ import division then your code for division. and you will always get a float division.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need add casting to `float`:

```
print (df.ab.value_counts()[1])/float(df.ab.count())
0.37608

print 18804/50000
0
print 18804/float(50000)
0.37608
print float(18804)/50000
0.37608
```

Comment: I even did df.ab.value_counts()[1])/(df.ab.count()*1.0) it didn't work too

Comment: No your count works with float. But if I use 1.0 instead of float it doesnt work

Comment: Just edited with a follow up question on bar graph. Could you help?

Comment: Yes, give me a minute.

Comment: Did you get the box plots

Comment: Yes, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36856462/2901002). Please check it. Thanks.

Comment: Pls check my comment there

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easier

```
df.ab.value_counts(normalize=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from __future__ import division
(df.ab.value_counts()[1])/(df.ab.count())  ###should give float value 0.3768
```

Have not tested it, but hopes it will help you.