# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'bar' in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame which is a pandas data frame type as shown below

```
type(df)

Out[176]:

pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

But when I try to use any plotting functions on this data frame like bar graph it gives an error as follows;

```
df.plot.bar()

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'bar'
```

Not other function like box plot or hist is also not working. Any idea why?

Comment: If plot is function, what will effect of df.plot().bar() ?

Comment: syntax says df.plot.bar() and not df.plot().bar() in the documentation

Comment: but runtime says that this is the function, so it worth try :)

Comment: See this. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html

Comment: Your things works but why? In docuementatin above it says plot without a function

Comment: Probably there is an mistake in documentation, or doc is outdated.

Comment: These plot 'submethods' were only added in version 0.17.0, see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#plot-submethods

Answer (score 2):

If you have specific columns in mind that you want to plot, you can try:
    `df.plot(x='x', y='y', kind='bar')`

Answer (score 1):

Interesting, for me it works very well:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ab': {0: 31196, 1: 18804}})
print df

      ab
0  31196
1  18804

#New in version 0.17.0.
df.plot.bar()
```

Another option:

```
df.plot(kind='bar')
```

[image: graph]

EDIT (by discussion in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110208/discussion-between-jezrael-and-baktaawar)):

I think you need [`boxplot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.boxplot.html):

```
#filter columns
df = df.drop(['city','last_trip_date','phone','signup_date','user_red'], axis=1)
print df
   Retained  avg_dist  avg_increase  avg_price  avg_value   pct  \
0         1      3.67           1.1        5.0        4.7  15.4   
1         0      8.26           1.0        5.0        5.0   0.0   
2         0      0.77           1.0        5.0        4.3   0.0   

   trips_in_first_30_days  weekday_pct  
0                     4.0         46.2  
1                     0.0         50.0  
2                     3.0        100.0  

df.boxplot(by='Retained', layout=(7,1), figsize=(5,15))
```

[image: graph]

Comment: No df is another data frame. Not this one. It is a bigger data frame with 12 columns and one column of that is 'ab'. What I am trying to do is I want to do bar and box plots of the columns in this df stacked or grouped by 'ab' column. But when I do df. plot.bar or df.plot.box anything it gives me the above error

Comment: see this. 

2]:

df.shape

Out[182]:

(50000, 13)

Comment: df.ab.plot.bar() doesnt work. But df.ab.plot().bar() gives something. But not the right bar graph. Like ab has two values 1 and 0. I want to plot the bar graph of 1 and 0 with their counts but just using ab as a column from df dataframe

Comment: I add new snippet to answer, I hope it works. But maybe it show bad graph. I think you need set  column with  `0` and `1` to `index` and then try `df.ab.plot(kind='bar')`. But the best is add sample of your `DataFrame` to question if it doesnt work.

Comment: What is version of your `pandas`?

Comment: its 0.15.2. Ok I just copied your first answer 

df = pd.DataFrame({'ab': {0: 31196, 1: 18804}})
print df

df.plot.bar()

it gives me the same error. Function has not attribute. Even df.plot().bar() gives an error 

bar takes three arguments. This is really very frustrating to see

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110208/discussion-between-jezrael-and-baktaawar).

Comment: hi I did similar too but it is very crowded. see here

plt.figure(figsize=(12,20))
df.boxplot(cols,by='Retained')

Comment: Nice, it seems be better.

Comment: Yeah but the box plot figure as such is very small. Its difficult to visualzie. I want the box plot of each column to be a bit big so that it is easier ti see